# How do I create all unique pairwise combinations of my sample dataset

Tags: r, combinations, pairwise

I have a list of 388 sample codes and I want all unique pairwise combinations.
I've tried several options in r but it still doesn't give me what I want.

This is a part of my sample codes:

```
11_07LENABL017

30_08ASBBAL033

21_08GEHOAL038

21_08GEHOAL041

04_08HLNABL043

31_08MMBBAL029

39_08VOVOAL030

39_08VOVOAL031

39_08VOVOAL039


So what is want is like this:

11_07LENABL017_30_08ASBBAL033

11_07LENABL017_21_08GEHOAL038

11_07LENABL017_21_08GEHOAL041
```

and so on

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)    
apply(combn(x,2),2,paste,collapse='_')
```

Output:

```
[1] "1_2" "1_3" "1_4" "1_5" "2_3" "2_4" "2_5" "3_4" "3_5" "4_5"
```

or, if you consider `a-b` and `b-a` to be different:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
with(subset(expand.grid(x,x),Var1!=Var2),paste0(Var1,'-',Var2))
```

Output:

```
[1] "2-1" "3-1" "4-1" "5-1" "1-2" "3-2" "4-2" "5-2" "1-3" "2-3" "4-3" "5-3" "1-4" "2-4" "3-4" "5-4"
[17] "1-5" "2-5" "3-5" "4-5"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can add the function in `combn`, i.e. `combn(x, 2, paste, collapse = '_')`

Comment: Nice, I did not know that!

Comment: Thanx Floriean, that works perfectly!